# Using consecutive line boundary with 'splitlines()'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, split

I am trying to use **consecutive line boundary** within `splitlines()` method.

```
grocery = 'Milk\nChicken\r\nBread\rButter'
print(grocery.splitlines())
```

When executing the above code, I am getting below output:

```
['Milk', 'Chicken', 'Bread', 'Butter']
```

However, the below code is giving a an extra empty list item:

```
grocery = 'Milk\nChicken\r\rBread\rButter'
print(grocery.splitlines())
```

Output:

```
['Milk', 'Chicken', '', 'Bread', 'Butter']
```

Why am I getting an extra empty list item in the second scenario?

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, the second `\r` is treated as a separate line, something similar happens when you do this:

```py
>>> grocery = 'Milk\nChicken\n\nBread\rButter'
>>> grocery.splitlines()
['Milk', 'Chicken', '', 'Bread', 'Butter']
```

When you use a combination of `\r\n`, that is treated as a newline as the carriage return-newline pair are both needed for newline in a terminal session.

Comment: But when I do `\r\n`, is it not creating two newlines?

Comment: `\r\n` is basically just a newline, try `print("hello\r\nhi")` on a terminal, `\r` is basically carriage return, so a combination of `\r\n` is what a new line is otherwise it just takes your cursor to the beginning of the line

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/python-string-splitlines-method refer the table here